# SwiftUI load data on push view OR reset on pop view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Swift 5.2
I have a NavigationView, for a tree of Views joined by NavigationLinks.  (No weirdness going on; no cycles or hopping between different parts of the tree - just views linking to subviews linking to subsubviews.)  One of them is a configuration screen.  I desire that when you arrive on the config screen (aka ConfigView), the configuration is loaded from disk.  In subviews of ConfigView, you can modify different settings, and on ConfigView you can save the settings.  However, I desire that if you pop ConfigView (leave, towards the root of the tree), your unsaved changes are discarded.

One of my initial thoughts was to load the changes in the ConfigView initializer.  This doesn't work, because ConfigView() is called in the parent view, so exiting the ConfigView and returning to ConfigView keeps the same ConfigView between views (and thus the same dirty data).  (...Or, the ConfigView is recreated multiple times without actually leaving it, causing the data to be erroneously reloaded.  I tried to test the conditions under which it did either, just now, but ran into a crash I'm not going to fix today.  Regardless, I tested it earlier today and it demonstrated one or both of the above behaviors.)
Perhaps load it in the body block?  But that gets re-run e.g. when you return from a subview link, which would erroneously reload the data.
Perhaps load it in `.onAppear`?  But that ALSO erroneously reloads the data when you return from a subview.
I considered perhaps going with the dual of my original intent, disposing of the dirty data when you pop the ConfigView (and reloading it whenever requested), but I haven't found any hooks I can use to be notified when e.g. the user hits the "back" button.

How do I get a clean copy of the data to be present on new entry to the ConfigView, and not lost until the ConfigView is popped?

Comment: In SwiftUI you shouldn't have any business logic in the view. It belongs in the model. What you need to do is provide your configuration view its own copy of the configuration model. When the user taps the save button, you call a function on the model that causes it to persist itself to disk.  You also need tell then rest of your app that there is a new configuration.  How you do this depends on how you access the config is accessed in your app. E.g. via the environment.  If the config view is exited without saving, the config copy is just thrown away.

Comment: @Paulw11 The logic and data IS contained in the model - the thing you said is basically what I'm doing already, and unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.  `If the config view is exited without saving, the config copy is just thrown away.` - depending on at what point I create the copy, it either doesn't get thrown away, or it gets recreated while I'm still inside the config screen.

Comment: I created a project that shows how I would tackle this - https://github.com/paulw11/ConfigurationSample Essentially you keep a "temporary" configuration object that you reset back to the current state when the main view appears.

Comment: @Paulw11 ...Oh, put the `.onAppear` in the PARENT of the config screen!  That has slightly different semantics than what I'd originally had in mind, but probably WILL work for my existing use case.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a persistence data somewhere in your app, and when passing data to a child view create a draft data (ObservableObject). Then, save the updated data to the persistence data whenever needed. This way, the child will only play with the draft data and your parent view will only show the persistence data.

There's a good example here: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls

Please have a look at all of the tutorials made by Apple, they are very short and powerful samples.

I will paste the code from the link above to here just in case the code is lost sometime in the future.

```
struct ProfileHost: View {
    @Environment(\.editMode) var mode
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @State var draftProfile = Profile.default

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                if self.mode?.wrappedValue == .active {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                        self.draftProfile = self.userData.profile
                        self.mode?.animation().wrappedValue = .inactive
                    }
                }

                Spacer()

                EditButton()
            }
            if self.mode?.wrappedValue == .inactive {
                ProfileSummary(profile: userData.profile)
            } else {
                ProfileEditor(profile: $draftProfile)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.draftProfile = self.userData.profile
                    }
                    .onDisappear {
                        self.userData.profile = self.draftProfile
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the key component of this is (abridged) `onAppear { draft = real }`.  I considered this approach in my question, but because the configuration screen has sub-screens, `onAppear` would trigger whenever you returned from a sub-screen, overwriting the draft.

Comment: It is really not clear what you want to achieve and what the real problem is. I want to help you, so can you update your question with the code snippet to have a better understanding?

Comment: When writing the question, I tried to state my question as clearly as possible.  I don't see where I have failed in that, so I can't really fix it.  Can you explain what about my question is unclear?  Like - I guess I could add some diagrams of the intended workflow; would that help?